# Angular HttpClientTesting with multiple requests

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to testing with Angular (v6) and am having trouble with a service that relies on a couple of other services.

I want to be able to flush with test data. However it never hits the callback in subscribe. I have no idea why. Thanks for your help!!

```
service.getAll().subscribe(data => {
  expect(data).toEqual(staticData)
})

// we expect call to users and groups on top of scheduled searches
const calls = httpTestingController.match((request) => {
  return request.url === usersApiUrl || request.url === groupsApiUrl || request.url === apiUrl
})
expect(calls.length === 3)
expect(calls[0].request.url).toEqual(apiUrl)

calls[0].flush(staticData)
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to flush the other calls. Duh!